Chip Identification - "+A0V" & "LBSS"
Would anyone know what the +A0V chip that looks like a BJT is. Measuring with a ruler the dimensions are approx. 1.5mm by 1mm. It is connected to this chip that I also don't know what it is, with marking 'LBSS B197 224' (4mm by 4mm). The second pin is connected to a relay and the third one is grounded. They are both located on a pressure sensor board.


Show more of the surrounding circuit. What makes you think it's a BJT? Dimensions would be nice too; is it a SOT-23, a SOT-323, or what?

@Hearth I added more information, seems like both of the chips arent connected to much as the second chip has a lot of capacitor connections that are then grounded. It also has the same relay connection as the A0V

Also, noticing the tags; do you have reason to think it's a Microchip part, or did you not realize Microchip is a brand?

@Hearth I didn't mean it is a brand no sorry

The one marked AOV is an Analog Devices/Maxim MAX7375AXR105 oscillator.


(Source: lcsc.com)

The one marked LBSS is an Analog Devices LTC2484 ∆Σ ADC.

